# Updating views from IBAction methods, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c

I am having a hard time understanding the following issue:

This code does what i think it should do: Initialize badges, move it after the initialization and update label on the badge:

- Initialize badge
- Set value to 24 (or some other number)
- Add UIView on screen
- Change UIView location
- Change value to read xx

> ```
> [self initializeCardBadges];
> [gameView addSubview:unplayedCountBadge];
>
> [unplayedCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(315, 5, 25, 25)]; // Moves
> unplayedCountBadge.badgeText = @"xx";                     // Updates label
> ```

where `initializeCardBadges` does the following:

```
self.unplayedCountBadge = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", decks.masterDeck.count]
                                        withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                           withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] 
                                         withBadgeFrame:YES 
                                    withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                              withScale:1.0
                                             withShining:YES];  

[self.unplayedCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(435, 5, 25, 25)];
```

Once the badge is in place, we are free to move it around and change text. As mentioned above this works.

When i add a new method to update the badge labels, as expected, all is well again

```
[self initializeCardBadges];
[gameView addSubview:unplayedCountBadge];

[unplayedCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(315, 5, 25, 25)]; // Moves badge to location
[self updateBadgeLabelForUnplayedCards];                  // Updates label

-(void) updateBadgeLabelForUnplayedCards {
    unplayedCountBadge.badgeText=@"yy";    
}
```

---

But .. when i add the same logic to `-(IBAction) doneWithThisRoundDealCards:(id)sender`, upon button tap ..

```
[unplayedCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(315, 5, 25, 25)]; // Moves
[self updateBadgeLabelForUnplayedCards];                  // Value NOT set
```

Additionally, when i replace the above with explicit commands, the same can be observed: badge moves location, value is not set

```
[unplayedCountBadge setFrame:CGRectMake(315, 5, 25, 25)];  // Moves
self.unplayedCountBadge.badgeText=@"tt";                   // Value NOT set
```

**Badge location changes, but ... text does not update. Why is this?**

I am reusing this [code](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) for badge generation.

Note that BadgeText is defined as a simple property, as shown [here](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge/blob/master/Classes/CustomBadge.h)

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *badgeText;
```

Comment: Is that -updateBadgeWith... method even being called?

Comment: Yes. Confirmed with logging and the fact that Badge location changes

Comment: Is it possible that the property badgeText is not properly setting the string in the badge, or that another method isn't changing the text after this is called?

Comment: Same exact code is used for setting the value. The only difference (that i can see) is that a method requesting the update is IBAction

Comment: can you add mor information about "badgeText" property?

Comment: IBAction is just a void return value that interface builder detects.  It doesn't change anything about the method, just how it is wired to the interface.  I would try setting the string inside the actual method instead of calling a secondary method inside of itself.  If that doesn't work, I'd check your implementation of the badgeText property.

Comment: @CodaFi Updated question to include more info

Comment: @LuisEspinoza, Updated question to include more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try

```
[unplayedCountBadge setNeedsDisplay];
```

?

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds .. damn it!

Comment: Indeed this works, however why is `[unplayedCountBadge setNeedsDisplay];` only needed when called from IBAction method?

Comment: It seems that because the implementation of the badge every time that you change the text, you have to render the badge again. The first time that you set the text, it has not been rendered yet, thats why the first set of text works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you are not using the `- (void) autoBadgeSizeWithString:(NSString *)badgeString` method for changing the badge text, but one thing I see in that method that is that it calls `[self setNeedsDisplay]` which you do not seem to.